# Graph API - Is OneDrive personal or OneDrive for Business (ODFB)

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Our Application makes use of **Microsoft Graph API** and communicates with OneDrive for Business (ODFB). Our primary use case are tenant administrators in ODFB.

I want to limit authentication to ODFB only. I have admin only permission scopes, but OD personal still happily authenticates.

Was thinking of using my site url endpoint, which works for ODFB but returns `404` for OD personal:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=mySite
```

Feels contrived though, plus user would be successfully authenticated before we can check whether this is OD for personal (which isn't ideal)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your authentication request URL, replace the `/common/` tenant with `/organizations/`. This will restrict authentication to only AAD accounts (i.e. OneDrive for Business).

You can find a detailed explanation in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).